# Jquery UI radio buttons separated for no apparent reason

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Here's a [live demo of the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/sirtaptap/kwpGn/3/) on JS Fiddle. I have some jquery UI radio buttons, and by setting the font-family on the body element, suddenly spaces appear between the buttonset, ruining the appearance and connectivity of the buttons. They look like this:
[image]

**Update:** the bug is now happening in all browsers, though slightly different in each browser. In all cases the font-family attribute is the problem.

I included some minimum CSS/HTML from my site that causes the issue, the Themeroller CSS for my site. You can mess with the fiddle and you'll see the gaps disappear when the font-family tag is removed from the `body` tag. Note it doesn't have to be a `body` tag, it happens if you make it a `div` or anything else that applies to the radio buttons.

This one bit of CSS is enough to break it:

```
body{
font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Is there any way I can specify the font family for the parent elements without the jquery UI buttons breaking? Interestingly this font-family isn't being used, as the Jquery UI theme's CSS sets the radio button's font as well.

Comment: I can't see that in Firefox, what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome latest on Windows 7. Actually it looks like it only happens on chrome now that I check everywhere.

Comment: It does that on firefox but there is a gap to the right of the middle button.

Comment: @bobek it's working/breaking in all browsers now, though Firefox breaks it slightly differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't tell you why it does it, but if you are happy just to add CSS code that fixes it then use this:

```
#radio input, #radio label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;  
}
```

#### Edit

In response to your comment below - try adding `!important` to `margin-right`; it looks like it is being over-ridden.

```
#radio input, #radio label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px !important;  
}
```

**JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kwpGn/7/**

Comment: Oops, I deleted the Fiddle you forked; but that solution DOES fix the problem in all browsers, both for the new Fiddle and for my full site. Thanks a bunch. I'm still interested to see why the margin is added though, my full CSS defaults to margin:0;

Comment: Actually now that I look this solution breaks the right border on all buttons but the rightmost one when in the Active and Hover states. You can see the problem here, I added your solution to the new JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sirtaptap/kwpGn/5/ . Tried tinkering with the margin/border properties in CSS but the right border's still gone.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know where this additional spacing is coming from. I have ammended my answer to accomodate the issue you are finding in the above comment.

Comment: Looks perfect, I'll accept this answer if by tomorrow no one knows why this happens. Not crazy about adding CSS for this but I've had to do worse (Thanks IE)